# Convert printf statement to cout?

Tags: c++, c

Hi could some one convert this c printf statement to a c++ cout statement?

```
    printf("\n\nLIST OF MOVIES:\n\n");
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as "C"?

Comment: Kerrek's on the money.  Separately, you'll see [`std::`]`endl` used in C++ too, which is equivalent to one `\n` and a flush of the stream (which `printf()` never explicitly requests).  It's noteworthy that in C++ `std::cin` and `std::cout` default to being "tied", which means `std::cout` is automatically flushed whenever you go to input from `std::cin`.

Comment: @TonyD, It's also noteworthy that when `std::cout` is destroyed at the end of the program, it flushes, so no hassle doing it for the last line of output you have or anything.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
std::cout << "\n\nLIST OF MOVIES:\n\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient way is

```
std::cout << "\n\nLIST OF MOVIES:\n" << std::endl;
```

Because endl also flush the buffer.

Comment: endl comes with cost of time . so using it unnecessarily is not efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cout<<"\n\nLIST OF MOVIES:\n\n";
```

or

```
std::cout<<endl<<endl<<"LIST OF MOVIES:"<<endl<<endl;
```

Comment: To be fair, those do different things. More specifically, the second flushes a lot more than needed.

Comment: and the second one is missing `std::` on the `endl`

Comment: They act as same only difference that I know is std::endl flushes the output buffer, and \n doesn't. If you don't want the buffer flushed frequently, use \n

Comment: Probably the recommendation would be `std::cout << "\n\nLIST OF MOVIES:\n" << std::endl;` That is, put just one `endl` and make it the last action after a "logical line" of output is done. This flush is important to see correct output in some terminals while debugging, e.g. the attached console in Qt Designer IDE and perhaps others.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clean solution, and really disadviced, you can use preprocessor to replace printf with std::cout:

```
#define printf(text) std::cout << text

int main()
{
    printf("\n\nLIST OF MOVIES:\n\n");
}
```